Issue with terraform import block
I am working on a Terraform configuration to manage IAM roles and accounts. I have the following module setup for IAM accounts:
Module Reference Block:
module "iam_accounts" {
  source           = "./iam-account"
  for_each         = var.iam_accounts
  iam_account_name = each.key
  roles            = each.value.roles
  account_type     = each.value.type
  project_id       = var.project_id
}

Base Module Code:
locals {
  roles_length = var.roles[0] == "" ? 0 : length(var.roles)
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "iam_account_members" {
  for_each = var.roles != "" && local.roles_length > 0 ? { for role in var.roles : role => true } : {}
  project  = var.project_id
  role     = each.key
  member   = "${var.account_type}:${var.iam_account_name}"
}

tfvars File:
{
  "project_id": "sample-project",
  "iam_accounts": {
    "some-iam-account@org.com": {
      "type": "group",
      "roles": [
        "organizations/111111111/roles/ProjectBillingViewer",
        "roles/aiplatform.user"
       ]
      }
  }
}

I want to import existing resources into the Terraform state using the import block. Here is what I tried:
Import Block:
import {
  for_each = var.iam_accounts
  id = each.value.roles
  to = module.iam_accounts[each.key].google_project_iam_member.iam_account_members[{for role in each.value.roles: role => true}]
}

However, I am getting the following error:
Error: Invalid address

  on main.tf line 45, in import:
  45:   to = module.iam_accounts[each.key].google_project_iam_member.iam_account_members[{for role in each.value.roles: role => true}]

Invalid resource instance key: either a string or an integer is required.

Question:
How can I dynamically import existing IAM resources into the Terraform state file using the import block? What is the correct way to reference these resources dynamically?
Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

What would happen if you were to move the value from the tfvars to a local block and use a local variable in the import block?
